# mergeObjects() in JSON gives error with dot in String

Tags: java, json

Library Used: https://github.com/octomix/josson

Hello I am merging data into existing JSON using above library

```
{
  "tbl05FlangeMasterSuction": {
    "flangeId": 3836,
    "flangetype": "RF",
    "size": 200,
    "layersOff": "",
    "specification": "ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF",
    "companionFlangeWt": "2",
    "maxPressure": 20,
    "layersOn": "",
    "uuid": "376E1B0D-1F60-4E8A-968C-D5033E190899"
  },
  "data": {
    "Check": "ok"
  }
}
```

JAVA Code

```
String a = "{\"tbl05FlangeMasterSuction\":{\"flangeId\":3836,\"flangetype\":\"RF\",\"size\":200,\"layersOff\":\"\",\"specification\":\"ANSIB16.5CLASS150RF\",\"companionFlangeWt\":\"2\",\"maxPressure\":20,\"layersOn\":\"\",\"uuid\":\"376E1B0D-1F60-4E8A-968C-D5033E190899\"},\"data\":{\"Check\":\"ok\"}}";
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(a);
String b = "field(data.mergeObjects(?,  json('{\"e1\":{\"expression\":\"$.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification.caseValue('ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF',100,365)\"}}')))";
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(b.toString());
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid function call field() : Invalid function call mergeObjects() : Invalid function call json() : Argument is not a valid string literal: '{"e1":{"expression":"$.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification.caseValue('ANSI B16
    at com.octomix.josson.FuncDispatcher.apply(FuncDispatcher.java:84)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:328)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:249)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathByExpression(JossonCore.java:211)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:147)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:142)
    at com.octomix.josson.Josson.getNode(Josson.java:279)
    at com.velotech.pumpselection.velotech.expressionCheck.main(expressionCheck.java:34)
```

I know the exception is because of "." in the string "ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF". But we cannot remove the dot.
Please help

Regards,
Pranav C Lunavat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not because of the ".". Instead, it is because of single quote.

In your expression, function `json()`'s parameter is a string literal that enclosed by single quote.  All single quote characters `'` inside the string need to be doubled. That becomes:

```
"field(data.mergeObjects(?,  json('{\"e1\":{\"expression\":\"$.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification.caseValue(''ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF'',100,365)\"}}')))";
```